# "Service Account Role" section using the Keycloak Admin REST API

Tags: keycloak-rest-api

I want to assign a custom role (ca_boarding_administrator_role) in the "Service Account Role" section using the **Keycloak Admin REST API**.

My client (cq-boarding-client) has the access type "confidential".

My goal is to have it available in the access_token under the realm_access.roles claim.

This documentation describes how to accomplish this in using the web UI. In my case I am trying to automate using the Admin REST API: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_service_accounts

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By taking a closer look at the Keycloak Resource Models I realized that for each confidential **Client** also a **User** is created. By adding the desired role to the realmRoles attribute of the **User** does the trick.

[image]

In case anybody is interested, I included my nodejs script to automate it: [service-account-role-mappings.js](https://gist.github.com/fnbk/4a4d94cf246705acd498c77652015543)

For additional reference:

- https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-admin-client
- https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation